# extjs, php works on double click, and i want to work on one click

Tags: extjs

in my php code i have a table with rows:

```
name             actions
category 1        edit
category 2        edit
.....             edit
```

every edit buttons have an id for ex: `<a href="edit('.$raw['id'].')" id="show-btn'.$raw['id'].'">`

now my function edit is:

```
var win;
var button;


function edit(idd){

    button = Ext.get('show-btn'+idd);

    button.on('click', function(){
        // create the window on the first click and reuse on subsequent clicks
        if(!win){


            win = new Ext.Window({
                applyTo:'hello-win',
                layout:'column',

                closeAction:'hide',
                plain: true,
                autoHeight:true,

                items: new Ext.FormPanel({
                    applyTo: 'hello-tabs',

                }),

                buttons: [{
                   text:'Modify',
                   handler: function(){

                        win.hide();
                        document.form_edit.submit();

                    }

                    },{
                        text: 'Close',
                        handler: function(){
                            win.hide();
                        }
                    }]
                });
        }
        win.show(this);

    });
};
```

This script works perfectly but on bauble click, how can i do this on one click.

I now the problem is on `button.on('click')`

Many thanks, please help me with this issues

Comment: by the way i don't want to use $(document).ready(.. because the effect disappear

Comment: What does PHP have to do with it? Also, I might be wrong but [click is just click](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Button.html#event-Ext.Button-click).

Comment: Now i observe something, first time it works o double click, after that in works on first click, I don't understand why doesn't work on first click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like some level of functionality is being added on your first click and then that is used for subsequent clicks.  I'd suggest putting either an alert or a `console.log` (if your browser supports it) inside of the edit function both before and after the `if(win)` test.

I'm also curious -- if you're trying to have this execute for an entire table, wouldn't that `win` global variable cause problems?

I think you're better off pre-populating win and using a local variable:

```
function edit(idd){

   button = Ext.get('show-btn'+idd);
   // this can be moved into button.on('click', function(){, but that may be 
   // causing the problem...
   // come to think of it... the example here: 
   // http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/window/hello.js
   // has this inside the button.on method.  You may want to try it both ways.
   if(!button.win){

        button.win = new Ext.Window({
            applyTo:'hello-win',
            layout:'column',

            closeAction:'hide',
            plain: true,
            autoHeight:true,

            items: new Ext.FormPanel({
                applyTo: 'hello-tabs',

            }),

            buttons: [{
               text:'Modify',
               handler: function(){

                    win.hide();
                    document.form_edit.submit();

                }

                },{
                    text: 'Close',
                    handler: function(){
                        win.hide();
                    }
                }]
            });
    }
    button.on('click', function(){
        // the window already exists, so no need to worry about creating it.
        button.win.show(this);

    });
};
```

Could that work?  If not, we will need to see more code.

Comment: I made it, i replace the  button.on('click', function(){
      
        button.win.show(this);

    });
with win.show(button);